# How to determine what commands DrJava is executing?

Tags: java, drjava

**Q**: How can I determine what commands DrJava is actually executing when I click "Compile"?

**CONTEXT**: I wrote a simple test program which used an external .jar. I added the path to that .jar in DrJava via Edit > Preferences > Resource Locations > Extra Classpath > Add. I want to know how `javac` is actually called from DrJava. E.g., is it

`javac -cp <path to the .jar> myprogram.java` or

`javac -cp .;<path to the .jar> myprogram.java` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

According to Dr Java instructions:

> Create Jar File from Project. You can create a jar file that contains the project's source code, its compiled class files, or both by selecting "Create Jar File from Project" in the Project menu. This will display a dialog that allows you to specify the jar file's location and what gets put into it. If you are placing class files into the jar file, you can make the jar file executable by selecting "Make executable" and entering the main class. **For more control over the properties of the jar, you may enter a custom manifest by selecting "Custom Manifest" and pressing the "Edit Manifest" button.** You may opt to include all source files in the jar, embeded in a seperate jar, by selecting "Jar source files". You can also include all files in the project directory by selecting "Jar All files".

Comment: Still not sure how to get from this to the answer. What is entered in the "Custom Manifest"? But even then, how does that tell me what commands DrJava executes when I click select "Compile"?